# PS: Check for installation, proceed if not present

Tags: powershell

It's been a while since I've been here!  I'm in a pickle with a script I put together to check whether an application is installed, if it's not to proceed with a scheduled task to get this staged for installation.  Reason for scheduled task is this software vendor does NOT support 3rd party management software.  It's been very frustrating.

The scheduled task portion works but when I check for the installation and then pass the script if it's not, I'm getting stuck.  Can someone be so kind to look this over and let me know what I'm missing?  Thank you in advance.

```
$software = "Screen Capture Module - 15.2.8.747";
$installed32 = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Like $software }).DisplayName -ne $null
$taskName = "ScreenCaptureInsScript"
$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\XXXXXX\Verint-SC\Install-script.bat'
$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 7:00
$taskPrincipal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "XXXXXXX\XXXXXXXX"
$taskSettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
    -Compatibility Win8 `
    -AllowStartIfOnBatteries `
    -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries `
    -StartWhenAvailable

If ($installed32 -eq $null) {
    # Register the scheduled task
    Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskName $taskName `
    -Action $taskAction `
    -Trigger $taskTrigger `
    -Description "Verint Screen Capture Installation Script Task" `
    -Settings $taskSettings `
    -RunLevel Highest `
    -Force

Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'ScreenCaptureInsScript' -User $taskPrincipal.UserID -Password 'xxXxxxXXXXx'
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "then pass the script if it's not, I'm getting stuck"?

Comment: Are you literally just looking to see if the application is installed? Or if it's installing?

Comment: So, I need to have detection logic in the script.  If that software match is not present, then I want the script to set the scheduled task for the installation.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$installed32` to a true/false value with `-ne $null`, but your `if` statement is checking whether `$installed32 -eq $null` instead of true/false. This means your `if` statement always evaluates to false, and doesn't run. For example:

```sh
# neither of the true/false bools evaluate to null
$null -eq $true
$false

$null -eq $false
$false
```

Instead, you probably want to simply test the true/false value:

```
if (-not $installed32) { Register-ScheduledTask... }
```

---

And a little bit of cleanup:

```
$software32 = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'

# Check for incompatible software before creating task
if ($software32.DisplayName -NotContains 'Screen Capture Module - 15.2.8.747') {
  Register-ScheduledTask ...
}
```

Comment: I'm going to make that revision and test it out.  Thank you!